# how to repeat certain amount of code

Tags: android, xml, web-services

I have created an application that connect on a web-server and reads an xml file,there will be an update in the xml on the webserver  every 5 minutes.I want to connect on the webserver by using my application to get this updated xml file.How can i do that?
this a sample code of my application

```
 HandlingXMLStuff doingwork=new HandlingXMLStuff();
        try {
            URL website=new URL(FinalURL);
            SAXParserFactory spf=SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser sp=spf.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader xr=sp.getXMLReader();         
            xr.setContentHandler(doingwork);
            xr.parse(new InputSource(website.openStream()));

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and this the code of class that handle the xml file

```
public class HandlingXMLStuff extends DefaultHandler{

    String street1=null,street2=null,street3=null,street4=null;

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        if(localName.equals("Street1"))
        {
             street1=attributes.getValue("data");

        }
        if(localName.equals("Street2"))
        {
            street2=attributes.getValue("data");

        }
        if(localName.equals("Street3"))
        {
            street3=attributes.getValue("data");

        }
        if(localName.equals("Street4"))
        {
            street4=attributes.getValue("data");

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for this you should decide to use `Service`, exactly `System Service` called `AlarmManager`.

I recommend to you have look at some tutorials, also check [A simple example of Alarm Service, using AlarmManager](http://android-er.blogspot.sk/2010/10/simple-example-of-alarm-service-using.html), [AlarmManager reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).